# Changing boolean value from view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model `organismereferent` which has a boolean value named `active`. What I'm trying to do is depending on what value it has do a different action.

So if it's active the button shows deactivate and allows the user to set active to false. So after that the button should show activate which will allow the user to set active back to true.

I tried making a method in my controller then calling that method from my index view but it gives me a `No route matches [POST] "/organismereferents/8"`. I'm pretty new to Ruby on Rails so there must be an easier way to accomplish that

View:

```
<table class="table table-hover">

<tr>
    <th>Nom Organisation</th>
    <th>Site Web</th>
</tr>

<% @organismes.each do |organisme| %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= organisme.nom_organisation %></td>
        <td><%= organisme.site_web %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', organismereferent_path(organisme), class: 'btn btn-info' %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_organismereferent_path(organisme), class: 'btn btn-warning' %></td>

        <% if organisme.active == false %>

        <td><%= link_to 'Activate', organismereferent_path(organisme), class: 'btn btn-danger',
                method: :activate,
                data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
        <% else %>

        <td><%= link_to 'Deactivate', organismereferent_path(organisme), class: 'btn btn-danger',
                method: :deactivate,
                data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>

        <% end %>

    </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

Controller:

```
def index
  @organismes = Organismereferent.all
end

def deactivate
  @organisme = Organismereferent.find(params[:id])
  @organisme.active = false
end

def activate
  @organisme = Organismereferent.find(params[:id])
  @organisme.active = true
end
```

If you need any more information I will be glad too add it.

Routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
# For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
get 'master/index'

resources :organismereferents

# Notre page principal
root 'master#index'
end
```

[image]

Comment: Could you post your routes.rb file? Also, from the command line, type `rake routes` and post the result.

Comment: @moveson Added it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have a few problems here.

First, in your views, the `link_to` helper `method` parameter doesn't want to know the name of your controller action. It wants to know the http method to use. For the actions you are doing, I think the most appropriate would be `PATCH`. So change those lines to `method: :patch`.

Second, you need to update your `routes.rb` file to include the routes you need. You can do that by replacing `resources :organismereferents` with the following:

```
resources :organismereferents do
  member { patch :activate }
  member { patch :deactivate }
end
```

Using the `member` designation indicates to Rails that you want to include an `:id` param in the URL. Now when you run `rake routes` you should see, in addition to what you already have, the following:

```
activate_organismereferents   PATCH  /organismereferents/:id/activate(.:format)   organismereferents#activate
deactivate_organismereferents PATCH  /organismereferents/:id/deactivate(.:format) organismereferents#deactivate
```

Third, you need to fix your path helpers. The first column returned by `rake routes` tells you the name of the Rails helper path that you can use in your `link_to` helpers. So in your Activate link, you'll need to change `organismereferent_path(organisme)` to `activate_organismereferent_path(organisme)`, and in your Deactivate link, use `deactivate_organismereferent_path(organisme)`.

Finally, in your controller actions, you are not saving the records after you change the boolean value. You will need to call `@organisme.save` to persist the change. Or if you would prefer to make the change and save it in a single line, you can use `@organisme.update(active: true)` and `@organisme.update(active: false)`.

Comment: Thank you so much it works perfectly and now I understand a little bit more how things work in rails :) Is there any way of making the page refresh itself after the changes? Forget it I added `redirect_to organismereferents_path` and it does the trick. Thanks so much for your help :)